# Odoo POS kitchen order printing without IOT Box or Epson configuration

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale

I have Odoo 15 Ent with POS modules installed
1- they have 3 kitchens and one printer per each kitchen is there
2- All printers connected using LAN
3- the users having tablets and create orders and i did activate the kitchen printing option
the default process should allow me to print the orders and products should be printed automatically on the related printer based on the product or item category

I am expecting to be able to print one order contains 6 items each two of these items belong to one category
each printer should print only its belongs items